# Dotnetnuke single instance with two different domain name

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am facing issue related to domain name.
I have a dnn website with two different domain one for english and another for chinese.
Below is the scenario:
for example : **https://testdomain.com/test-test/test-test** ----> working properly
but **[https://testdomain.net.cn/test-test/test-test**---->](https://testdomain.net.cn/test-test/test-test**----%3E) The service is unavailable.

but https://testdomain.net.cn is loading properly but when loading this url **https://testdomain.net.cn/test-test/test-test** it is showing The service is unavailable.

I want to know what causing the issue to ".net.cn" so that it is not loading the page.
Any leads will be  appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Dnn is using a parameter for the language - therefore, I would do something like

https://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com/en

https://www.example.cn -> https://www.example.com/cn

in IIS.